# How to copy the home directory in the home directory?

Tags: file-copy, home

I need to make a copy of my home directory and place that copy in the same home directory. The exit code of the command must be `0`. Currently, my home directory does not contain any other directories.

Is there a better way than the following? (pwd is the home directory)

```
mkdir /tmp/temp && cp * /tmp/temp && mv /tmp/temp .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call rsync and exclude the directory where you're putting the copy.

```
cd
mkdir copy
rsync -a --exclude=copy . copy
```

Copying `*` excludes dot files (files whose name begins with a `.`), which are common and important in a home directory.

Answer (score 1):

That will neglect to copy any `.*` files that may exist in your home directory. I'd probably use `rsync` like so:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/temp && rsync -av . /tmp/temp/. && rsync -av /tmp/temp/ .
```

I'm not that thrilled about doing this as a chain of `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`, since problems can occur, but if you're careful it should be OK.

Comment: Nice use of `rsync`!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a temporary directory in your home directory itself and then copying?

```bash
mkdir tmp
for item in *
do
    if [[ "$item" != tmp ]]
    then 
        cp "$item" tmp
    fi
done
```

This is an alternative, but can't say if better though.